# Firefox Video Links - Open as VLC Network Stream

Tags: firefox, vlc, streaming, media, stream

If I click a link in Firefox and select open with vlc, it downloads the entire file, before opening it in vlc media player and playing it. Chrome is even worse and will keep the file in your downloads directory instead of `/tmp` If I do the same thing on my android tablet (click the video link) it will **not** download the entire file and then play it, but **stream it in the player**. I can copy and paste the link into vlc->open network stream which has the desired effect, but how can I make firefox/chrome do this automatically? I don't want to keep filling my tiny 60GB ssd's /tmp folder and having to reboot or manually remove the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [vlc contect menu addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/vlc-context-menu/) that seems to be doing the trick for now. When you right click, you can select `add url to vlc playlist`. 
However, it doesn't provide default functionality for if you click on the link, and you have to make sure to select the right option from the right click menu.